Kubuntu 24.04 GUI crashing but O/S still running
I'm running Kubuntu, which I installed on a HP Elitebook G5 a few months back.  It has all updates applied.
Maybe twice a week I will have the KDE desktop hang.  The mouse still works and can be seen moving about the scree, but nothing responds to mouse or keyboard clicks.
The O/S is still running, and if I SSH into the laptop I have full access, and I'm able to run the reboot command.  However, if I do reboot, it hangs closing down.
The laptop is dual boot, and on the rare occasions I use Windows,I have no issues at all.
Anyone got any ideas how I can fix this, or at least diagnose the problem?

I hadn't considered hardware issues, as it works fine in the rare occasion I use Windows, but then I suppose I don't use Windows for long enough.  I'll look at diagnostics software

If it works in Windows that likely rules out the possibility of a hardware issue. It's more likely a software issue in Ubuntu.
